# Is it possible to get the ndk's linker to run with multithreading enabled?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ld

we've a giant library consisting of millions lines of code, it is targeted for iOS and Android.

On iOS linking is super fast, several seconds.
On Android using the latest NDK to this date, it's by a factor slower, takes about 4 minutes on the same machine.

Note: I'm on macOS Mojave

When I checked NDK's ld on activity monitor it showed that it uses a single thread.

Is there a way to get it to use multithreading? (Hoping for a meaningful speed boost)

Note that we use CMake with a ninja generator.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I found the following in the January r21 release of the NDK release notes:

```
LLD is now available for testing. 
AOSP is in the process of switching to using LLD by default and the NDK will follow (timeline unknown). 
Test LLD in your app by passing -fuse-ld=lld when linking
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/revision_history

I confirm that LLD used 9 threads on my MacBook Pro (2.9Ghz Core i7 CPU)
Linkage that used to take 4+ minutes takes less than a minute, awesome!